# Таймер на JavaScript

Tags: таймер, javascript

Помогите написать таймер на JavaScript.
Нужно чтобы он отсчитывал время до заданной даты (время читается с компа).
Выводиться таймер должен так:

```
<span class="count-hour-1">1</span>
<span class="count-hour-2">0</span>
:
<span class="count-min-1">1</span>
<span class="count-min-2">7</span>
:
<span class="count-sec-1">5</span>
<span class="count-sec-2">9</span>
```

Дней нет, так что если дней больше чем 1, нужно переводить их в часы. 
(Например 2 дня - 48 часов).

Киньте ссылки, если такой таймер уже где то реализован. Я не нашел к сожалению.

Answer (score 3):

[Тут есть пример](http://javascript.ru/forum/dom-window/4869-skript-obratnogo-otschjota-vremeni.html)

Вот тут есть пример таймера с обратным отсчетом, надеюсь с тем, как воспользоваться этим таймеров в своих целях вы разберетесь.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function timer(){
 var obj=document.getElementById('timer_inp');
 obj.innerHTML--;

 if(obj.innerHTML==0){alert('Hello');setTimeout(function(){},1000);}
 else{setTimeout(timer,1000);}
}
setTimeout(timer,1000);
</script>
<div id="timer_inp">10</div>
```

---

**Добавлено**

Как сделать из этого то, что тебе нужно:

1. Делаем переменную (далее T), которая отвечает за оставшееся время (можно в секундах) (немного погуглить или задать правильные вопросы, и можно узнать как это сделать).
2. В таймере, уменьшаешь из этой переменной T вычитаем 1 секунду (тут особо ума не надо, просто небольшие навыки в программировании. Опять же можно погуглить).
3. Также в таймере переводим эту переменную Т в 6 цифр, и помещаем их нужные нам элементы (аналогично, узнать можно).

**Итог:** Если вы не лентяй, то сможете разобраться с этим сами :)

Comment: Я не очень силен в js. Мне нужен готовый вариант.

Comment: Тогда тебе на биржу фрилансеров в качестве заказчика

Comment: @DmitryScaletta, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @DmitryScaletta дописал немного, может поможет разобраться с этим :)

Answer (score 2):

[Вот, кажется, то, что вам нужно.](http://webbystep.ru/all-posts/16-js-clock/)

UPD: Вот вам практически готовое решение. Вам остается лишь написать вывод в html.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function Timer (date) {
    var s = (new Date(date)).getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();
    s = parseInt(s / 1000);

    var h = parseInt(s / 3600);
    s -= h * 3600;
    var m = parseInt(s / 60);
    s -= m * 60;

    console.log(h + ':' + m + ':' + s);
    
    if ((new Date(date)).getTime() >= (new Date()).getTime()) setTimeout('Timer(\'' + date + '\');', 1000);
}

Timer('September 1, 2013');
</script>
```

Comment: к сожалению немного не то:
"Для создания таймера будем отталкиваться от стартового времени указанного в секундах, в примере 7200 (2 часа). Сначала из скрытого блока <div style="display: none" class="ts">7200</div>"
А мне нужен отсчет до определенной даты, а не конкретный промежуток

Comment: Так, расчитайте сколько надо до определенной даты.

Answer (score 0):

Этот должен подойти: [Таймер обратного отсчета на `jQuery`](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=32&id=1341)